# Creating more than one record in binary file using a structure

Tags: c++, struct, binaryfiles

I'm trying to write a program that keeps student records in a binary file. When I write more than one record it only displays the last one written. How can I display more than the last record?  Does it have something to do with how I input the information?

Comment: _append_ data to the file. :/

Comment: You are not even close to accomplish your goal. 1) You have to take care of writing and reading `std::string` differently than you are doing it now. 2) You are not writing all the records that you are reading in the loop. 3) You are not reading all the records from the file either.

Comment: you should open the file only in the create or read function. IN create open it in append mode, in display open it in read mode

Comment: `in.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&info), sizeof(student));`  I just want to know the name of the book(s) that shows this construct that thought this was a good idea.  It has to be an often read one, since I see this question come up over and over again with practically the same problems and issues.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with the shown code.

1) std::string is not an array. When you write std::string to a file, like that, all that ends up happening is writing the raw binary pointers in the std::string structure, more or less, that happen point to the actual dynamically-allocated memory on the heap, where the contents of the actual string are in the original process that wrote the file.

Think of a std::string as a pointer. The std::string object manages the pointer, and takes care of allocating memory for it. It's actually a little bit more complicated than just a pointer, but for the purpose of this discussion, it's just a pointer. So, when you have:

```
char *p;

in.write(&p, sizeof(p));
```

What you end up doing here is not writing the actual string, whatever it is, but the internal memory address that p points to. So, if say, the actual pointer p's value is the memory address 0x40823f0e (just some random memory location), you'll end up writing this memory address to the file (either 4 or 8 bytes, depending on whether you're writing a 32-bit platform).

You can't just read/write std::strings-s into a file. All you'll end up writing to a file is meaningless binary garbage, which, once read in, is unlikely to make any sense in the completely different process that reads it. The best that will happen is you'll get nonsensical results. The worst (and the most likely) result, is corrupted memory, and a crash.

One thing you should be aware of is that sizeof() is always a constant, that's computed by the compiler. This code always ends up writing a fixed number of bytes to the file, right?

So, stop and think about this: you are writing a fixed number of bytes to a file, with sizeof(). Does it make sense to you, for this to happen, when your std::string in this structure could have only a few characters, or a million characters? There is no inherent limit in the number of characters in a std::string. It's only limited by your available memory.

2) create() writes an empty structure in the file. Before prompting for its contents. Generally, first you want to fill in some structure, and then write it to a file. Not the other way around.

3) display() opens the file with `ios::out`. That is, for writing. Opening a file for writing, and then attempting to read from it, is not going to produce useful results.